# Is the predecessors number check in dominance frontiers algorithm necessary?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, static-analysis

Here is a dominance frontiers algorithm, mentioned on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form):

```
for each node b
    dominance_frontier(b) := {}
for each node b
    if the number of immediate predecessors of b ≥ 2
        for each p in immediate predecessors of b
            runner := p
            while runner ≠ idom(b)
                dominance_frontier(runner) := dominance_frontier(runner) ∪ { b }
                runner := idom(runner)
```

My question is why do we need to check that there are at least two immediate predecessors of b? If there is just one, it would be the immediate dominator of b, thus the inner loop won't do anything.